# Append an object to an IEnumerable<> via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I need to be able to access a property via reflection, and, knowing that this property is an IEnumerable, append an object to it.

Something like this:

```
Object o;
MemberInfo m;

Array arr; // Except use IEnumerable, may have to take account of value/ref types
arr = (Array)((PropertyInfo)m).GetValue(o, null); }

List<o.GetType()> newArr = new List<o.GetType()>(); /* fails */
newArr.AddRange(arr);
newArr.Add(o);

((PropertyInfo)m).SetValue(o, newArr.ToArray(), null);
```

Can you help me where I'm going wrong :-)

Solution:

See accepted answer comments.  Also ([Get the actual type of a generic object parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371347/get-the-actual-type-of-a-generic-object-parameter/1371378#1371378)) is of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're essentially asking how to make a `List<T>` based on an unknown-at-compile-time type.  For this you'll have to use a bit more reflection magic:

```
Type genericListType = typeof(List<>);
Type listType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(o.GetType());
object listInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

That would create a `List<T>` out of a runtime type.

But really, your code would be much simpler if you simply use ArrayList:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(arr);
list.Add(o);
Array newArray = list.ToArray(o.GetType());
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Unfortunately I don't think I can write a generic solution that deals with properties of string[], List<string>, List<RandomObject> (even leaving out Dictionary<k,v>).  The problem is that you can't cast say listInstance to a List<T> in order to append and even if I created an IEnumerable<T> I can't replace a property field of type List<T> with this new created object.

Comment: Is it possible to step back and consider the overall problem you are solving, to see if you can make use of a more compile-time friendly approach? Reflection is powerful but ends up being complicated and hard to maintain.

If you can't change what you are doing, there still is a way to support everything you mentioned, it just requires ugly reflection code. I would probably forget about replacing the underlying reference and just look for an Add method that I could use (e.g. propertyType.GetMethod("Add")) and then special-case handling of arrays.

Comment: It's for generically mapping code classes against a data file so reflection has to be the answer.  Thanks, though, in combination your idea and this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371347/get-the-actual-type-of-a-generic-object-parameter/1371378#1371378) + handling of Arrays helped :-)

Answer (score 4):

Once you have an IEnumerable type, use something like this to append to it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> original, T next)
{
    foreach (T item in original) yield return item;
    yield return next;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> original, params T[] next)
{
    foreach (T item in original) yield return item;
    foreach (T item in next) yield return item;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> original, IEnumerable<T> next)
{
    foreach (T item in original) yield return item;
    foreach (T item in next) yield return item;
}
```

Comment: Though you have to rename those methods Append<T>