# .NET generic class instance - passing a variable data type

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, reflection, dynamic-typing

As the title suggests, I'm tyring to pass a variable data type to a template class. Something like this:

```
frmExample = New LookupForm(Of Models.MyClass) 'Works fine

Dim SelectedType As Type = InstanceOfMyClass.GetType() 'Works fine
frmExample = New LookupForm(Of SelectedType) 'Ba-bow!
frmExample = New LookupForm(Of InstanceOfMyClass.GetType()) 'Ba-bow!
```

---

```
LookupForm<Models.MyClass> frmExample;
Type SelectedType = InstanceOfMyClass.GetType();
frmExample = new LookupForm<SelectedType.GetType()>(); //Ba-bow
frmExample = new LookupForm<(Type)SelectedType>(); //Ba-bow
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with the template being processed at compile time but even if I'm off the mark there, it wouldn't solve my problem anyway. I can't find any relevant information on using Reflection to instance template classes either.

(How) can I create an instance of a dynamically typed repository at runtime?

Comment: You're not going to find any information at all on creating a dynamic template in VB.NET or C#, since neither language supports templates. They both support generics, which are substantially different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A C# example of something pretty close is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371347/get-the-actual-type-of-a-generic-object-) on a question I had:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("Foo").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { param.GetType() }).Invoke(null, new[] { param });
```

Converting to VB.NET, changing it to type creation not method invocation and using your example names for you:

```
Dim frmExample as LookupForm<Models.MyClass>;
Dim SelectedType as Type = InstanceOfMyClass.GetType();   
Dim GenericLookupType as Type = GetType(LookupForm(Of)).MakeGenericType(SelectedType)
frmExample = Activator.CreateInstance(GenericLookupType, new object(){})
```

(Ah for some reason I thought you wanted it in VB.NET but here is a C# example)

```
LookupForm<Models.MyClass> frmExample;
Type SelectedType = InstanceOfMyClass.GetType();   
Type GenericLookupType = typeof(LookupForm<>).MakeGenericType(SelectedType);
frmExample = Activator.CreateInstance(GenericLookupType, new object[]{});
```

Comment: Possibly because the original title had VB.NET at the start and the question only had a VB.NET example :) I removed the title reference and added a C# hoping to tap a larger mindset.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. You'll find out about lots of little rabbit holes with most of the applications of this kind of stuff, but it's a good way to find boundary cases of a language.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Type.MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx).

```
Type modelType = typeof(Models.MyClass);
var repoType = typeof(LookupForm<>).MakeGenericType(new [] {modelType} );
//at this point repoType == typeof(LookupForm<Models.MyClass>);
var repo = Activator.CreateInstance(repoType );
//Ta-dah!!!
```

And VB.NET version :)

```
    Dim modelType As Type = GetType(Models.MyClass)
    Dim repoType As Type = GetType(LookupForm(Of )).MakeGenericType(New Type() {modelType})
    'at this point repoType = GetType(LookupForm(of Models.MyClass))'
    Dim repo = Activator.CreateInstance(repoType)
    'Ta-dah!!!'
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a candidate for the Dynamic Language Runtime, 'Dynamic' type in C#, but that would require you to use .NET 4.0

Comment: I think you'd still have to use Activator.CreateInstance but you could deal with that better at compile time {i.e. LookupForm<SomeInstanceType> a = (LookupForm<SomeInstanceType>)Activator.CreateInstance(etc.); } and ensure that SomeInstanceType matched other dynamically generated types. Kind of hard to explain right now but you no doubt know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this without reflection and even then its not very friendly. The reflection code will looks something like this:

```
Type baseType = typeof(LookupForm<>);
Type selectedType = InstanceOfMyClass.GetType(); //or however else you want to get hold of it
Type genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { selectedType });
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Of course now you don't know what to cast your object to (assuming `selectedType` was dynamically set), but you can still call the methods on it via reflection, or you could create a non-generic interface to cast it to & call the methods on that.

Comment: It doesn't have to be friendly in implementation as long as the interface plays nice :)